# How to stop mails from triggering via workflow when an item is liked in discussion forum in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, discussion-board, workflow-activity

I have created a discussion forum in SharePoint 2013 it has a workflow which sends an email when a new item is added or an existing item is modifies. But, when an item in the discussion forum is liked or disliked, workflow is getting triggered as item is getting modified. How do I make it stop. I want mails to get sent when any other changes are made to ay item but not when any item is liked or disliked.

Comment: How had you made like/dislike function? Is it additional field in the list, that up/down by code?

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly the same issue. I've solved it with 3 simple steps:

1. Added a "Yes/No" column called "Send email" to the Posts list.
2. Added an If clause into the workflow which checks if the mark is ticked.
3. Put a "Send email" workflow action inside the If clause.

The good addition to it could be an action to uncheck the mark right after email sending, inside the If clause.

Hope this helps.
-- Best regards, Evgeny Victorov.